# Make UIButton Clickable while Moving it

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to move a button while being able to click it, but when I move the button, it can only be clicked on the end position. This is what I have so far:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, 
        delay: 0.1,
        options: .allowUserInteraction,
        animations: {
        self.clickButton.center = CGPoint(x: self.clickButton.center.x, 
        y:self.clickButton.center.y + 500)
}, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

The solution to your problem is to use `UIViewPropertyAnimator` instead of `UIView.animate` like this:

```swift
UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 5.0, curve: .easeInOut) {
    self.clickButton.center = CGPoint(
        x: self.clickButton.center.x,
        y:self.clickButton.center.y + 500
    )
}.startAnimation()
```

#### Explanation

I ran a demo project containing your code and what I found was the following. You can actually try clicking the end position of your button **BEFORE** it is animated there, and the click would still work.

[image]

`UIView` *could* be using CoreAnimation (`CALayer` animations) under the hood, and using classes like `CABasicAnimation` the same issue you experienced still exist.

I do not know the exact reason for the issue (because the iOS SDK is closed source) but this is my approximation.

Changing `clickButton.center` property within the `UIView.animate` block causes changes in the underlying `CALayer` object's properties. Changes in the `CALayer` object are what actually animates the views on screen.

However, touch gestures are usually processed by `UIView` objects because they inherit from `UIResponder` (unlike `CALayer` which inherits directly from `NSObject` only).

Since the `clickButton.center` property is set to the new value before the `CALayer` animation completes, touch gestures code does not "see" the intermediate values of the `.center` property. It just reads the final value which was set in the `UIView.animate` block. That is why I believe clicking on the end position still works while the animation is in-flight.

Using `UIViewPropertyAnimator` it presumably changes the actual `UIView` properties as well.

From the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator):

> The animator operates on animatable properties of views, such as the frame, center, alpha, and transform properties, creating the needed animations from the blocks you provide.

#### References

If you want to read more about the internal workings of `UIView` Animations, there's a great stack overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15189303/3178477).

[Apple's Official Documentation on CABasicAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cabasicanimation)

[Apple's Official Documentation on UIViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator)

[Apple's Official Documentation on UIResponder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder)