# Changing button frame stopping UIButton action

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

```
 notificationsDetailsButton.frame.origin.y += 50
 notificationsDetailsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapNotifications), for: .touchUpInside)
```

why `notificationsDetailsButton.frame.origin.y` stopping `didTapNotifications` trigger. i have checked `notificationsDetailsButton` in top of hierarchy & userintraction is enabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make UIButton Clickable while Moving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68147936/make-uibutton-clickable-while-moving-it)

Comment: is your button still disabled after you layoutSubviews() ?

Comment: @Mr.SwiftOak I got the issue. my button was inside UIVIew so it was not clickable because it moved outside bounds